# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Physical memory usage is too high: physicalBytes (1100M) > maxPhysicalBytes (1024M)

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, javacv, javacpp

When I record video using FFmpegFrameRecorder it shows me this error

```
   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-36
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Physical memory usage is too high: physicalBytes (1100M) > maxPhysicalBytes (1024M)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer.deallocator(Pointer.java:588)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Pointer.init(Pointer.java:124)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec$AVPacket.allocate(Native Method)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.avcodec$AVPacket.<init>(avcodec.java:1516)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
```

. Can anyone please help me to solve this Physical memory issue?

Comment: *solve this Physical memory issue* - Buy more memory

Comment: @ScaryWombat i have already added "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx8192m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError" this line in gradle.properties file.

Comment: Use less memory.  Very likely you have a leak.  Use the profiler to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to add the large heap tag in your manifest:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element

Answer (score 0):

There was a memory leak that has since been fixed:
https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/issues/1068